# What's the measure of the angle OCB in the triangle below?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference:

> The triangle $ABC$ is inscribed in a circle; the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ intersects $BC$ at $M$ and the extension of $AC$ at $N$.
> Calculate $\angle OCB$ if $O$ is the center of the circle;
> and $OH= OM = MN$ ($H$ is the midpoint of $AB$). (Answer: $18,5^\circ$)

My progress:

[image]

Draw $BN$.

$NO = 2OH \implies O$ is centroid $\triangle ABN$

$\angle HBY = \angle DYB\\
\angle DYN = \angle A$

$\triangle NYH $ is isosceles $\implies \angle MNY = \angle YHN$

$YM$ is a midsegment of $\triangle AON \implies YM \parallel AO\\ \therefore \angle OAY - \angle MYN$

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying Menelaus's theorem in $\triangle ANH$ where traversal $CB$ intersects $NA$ and $NH$ internally and $AH$ externally.

$ \displaystyle \frac{AB}{BH} \cdot \frac{HM}{MN} \cdot \frac{NC}{CA} = 1 \implies CA = 4 NC$

Say the foot of the perp from $O$ to $CA$ is $G$ then,

$ AG = GC = \frac12 CA = 2 NC, NG = 3 NC, NA = 5 NC$

Now note that $\triangle OGN \sim \triangle AHN$.

So, $ ~ \displaystyle \frac{NH}{NA} = \frac{NG}{NO} \implies \displaystyle \frac{NH}{NA} = \frac{3NA/5}{2NH/3}$

$NH^2 = \dfrac9{10} NA^2 \implies AH^2 = \dfrac1{10} NA^2$

$NH = 3 AH \implies \angle ANH \approx 18.5^\circ$

Finally, $\angle OCB = \angle OBC = 90^\circ - \angle A = \angle ANH$

Comment: Thanks, Great alternative to perpendicular $OG$. Just one question. Could you clarify $\angle OBC = 90^o - A$?

Comment: $BC$ subtends $\angle A$ at the circumference so it subtends twice the angle at center $O$ and also $OB = OC$. So $\angle OBC = \angle OCB = \frac12 (180^\circ - 2 \angle A)$